# Devise routes issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to adopt devise to my app

Here is the content of  Routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get "admin/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    delete "admin/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end


end
```

When I try to access /admin/login everything works fine, but when I try to access /admin/logout I get

```
No route matches [GET] "/admin/logout"
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using GET on the URL. You should use DELETE. Specify in the link `:method => :delete`, which is the proper HTTP verb for destroy action.

Comment: Can you show me an example because I can't understand what you mean ?

Comment: which means use <%= link_to "Sign out", "/admin/logout", :method => :delete %>.Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using user as a namespace then just check your routes in console by putting rake routes it will give you complete route table along with method.